# Issues with isolating color channels in Pylab

Tags: python, numpy

I want to plot a `numpy` 2d matrix with a specific color. In the example, the color is red. If I just use `imshow`, then it plots the correct function, but it plots it in a heatmap colorscale. This is great for viewing maxima, minima, etc. but I want to merge 3 images into the same one and isolate each image as a RGB channel in the combined image.

I wasn't getting what I expected, so I compared the isolated R value and tried using `imshow` with it and clearly don't get the same thing as I do when I just use `imshow` on the 2D (single channel) matrix. What is causing this?

Please note, that I want to use `pylab` (not `PIL`, `Image`, etc. - I want to accomplish this task in `pylab` using `imshow`)

The following script is a minimum example of the issue I am having:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
from pylab import *

nn = 1000
nx = nn
ny = nn
xs = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, nx) 
ys = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, ny) 

fs = np.zeros([nx,ny])

fmax = 4000.0

natoms = 4 
Xs = 10.0*random(natoms)
Ys = 10.0*random(natoms)
als = 10.0*random(natoms)
for ix in range(nx):
    x = xs[ix]
    for iy in range(ny):
        y = ys[iy]
        fv = 0.0 
        for iat in range(natoms):
            X = Xs[iat]
            Y = Ys[iat]
            r = sqrt( (X-x)*(X-x) + (Y-y)*(Y-y) )
            al = als[iat]
            fv += fmax*exp( -al*r )
        fs[ix,iy] = fv

figure(1)
imshow(fs)

figure(2)
A = np.zeros([nx, ny, 3]) 
A[:,:,0] = np.copy(fs)
imshow(A)

show()
```

I have included an example here - the red image should show the same qualitative features as the heatmap image, but it shows something ... wacky?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A few things in front

#### imports

you should not do `from pylab import *` and `import numpy as np`. `pylab` consists of `matplotlib.pyplot` and `numpy`. Good style would be importing the single modules and not all into the global namespace.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

`imshow`, `show` are functions from `pyplot`, so you need to prefix them with `plt.`. `sqr`, `exp` etc. are functions from `numpy`, so prefix them with `np.`

#### Faster and simpler way of calculating the image

Using `numpy.meshgrid` you can get the calculation for one atom without any python `for`-loop.

```
n_pixel_x = n_pixel_y = 1000
pixel_x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, n_pixel_x)
pixel_y = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, n_pixel_y)
pixel_x, pixel_y = np.meshgrid(pixel_x, pixel_y)
```

Gives you 2 2d-arrays with `x` and `y` values for each image pixel.
This simplifies the calculation of the image of a single atom to this:

```
r = np.sqrt((x - pixel_x)**2 + (y - pixel_y)**2)
single_image = fmax * np.exp(-al * r)
```

#### "If you are using `for i in range(N)` to access array members, you are doing it wrong"

Use the `zip` function:

```
n_atoms = 4
atoms_x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, n_atoms)
atoms_y = np.random.uniform(0, 10, n_atoms)
atoms_al = np.random.uniform(0, 10, n_atoms)

for x, y, al in zip(atoms_x, atoms_y, atoms_al):
    r = np.sqrt((x - pixel_x)**2 + (y - pixel_y)**2)
    single_image = fmax * np.exp(-al * r)
    image += single_image
```

## Now to the colormap problem:

The `plt.imshow()` command renders a 2d Array using a `colormap`, this
is a function that converts the value of the 2d array into a color.

The default colormap is `jet`, which gives this rainbow shape.
Other useful colormaps are `gray` for a simple gray scale image or `hot` for black body radiation.
`gray` is suitable in my opinion for showing a single color channel.

`plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray)`

All available colormaps are shown here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

### Why is using the RGB image different from showing a 2d-Array?

If you give `plt.imshow` an RGB array (so an array with shape (x, y, 3)), matplotlib expects the values to be in [0, 1]. So you have to normalize them before you plot them.

```
image_rgb = np.zeros([n_pixel_x, n_pixel_y, 3])
# normalize the image to values in [0, 1]
normalized_image = (image - image.min()) / (image.max() - image.min())
image_rgb[:, :, 0] = normalized_image

plt.imshow(image_rgb)
```

#### Using RGB channels:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

def normalize_image(image):
    a = np.min(image)
    b = np.max(image)
    return (image - a) / (b - a)

n_pixel_x = n_pixel_y = 1000
pixel_x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, n_pixel_x)
pixel_y = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, n_pixel_y)

pixel_x, pixel_y = np.meshgrid(pixel_x, pixel_y)


fmax = 4000.0

image_rgb = np.zeros([n_pixel_x, n_pixel_y, 3])
for i in range(3):
    image = np.zeros([n_pixel_x, n_pixel_y])
    n_atoms = 4
    atoms_x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, n_atoms)
    atoms_y = np.random.uniform(0, 10, n_atoms)
    atoms_al = np.random.uniform(0, 10, n_atoms)

    for x, y, al in zip(atoms_x, atoms_y, atoms_al):
        r = np.sqrt((x - pixel_x)**2 + (y - pixel_y)**2)
        single_image = fmax * np.exp(-al * r)
        image += single_image

    image_rgb[:, :, i] = image

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.title('RGB')
plt.imshow(normalize_image(image_rgb))

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.title('R')
plt.imshow(image_rgb[:, :, 0], cmap='gray')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.title('G')
plt.imshow(image_rgb[:, :, 1], cmap='gray')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.title('B')
plt.imshow(image_rgb[:, :, 2], cmap='gray')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something here, but I don't think this solves the problem. I am not just trying to change the colormap, I actually *need* to isolate the 3rd index and plot that as red. Imagine there is a second matrix and you want to plot that in blue alongside the red image. I can update if you want, but I don't think I can plot 3 matrices, on the same image, differentiated by color, by just using colormaps, can it?

Comment: Oh, than I misunderstood. You want to have 4 images side by side? The single color channels and the full image? Or do you want to have one atom in each color channel?

Comment: I would like to, for example, have the example atomic image as channel red. Suppose there was a new function (`gs`, rather than `fs`), I want that one to be assigned to `A[:,:,1]` so that it shows up at a green channel when I plot `A`. A third function (`hs`?) would go into the blue channel (`A[:,:,2]`) and then I can plot them all in the same image using RGB to identify different signals.

Comment: For now, however, I just want to get a single channel working correctly as it can easily be extrapolated to the other two channels.

Comment: Ah, I see. You concern is, that the results are different?

Comment: My concern is that the example red image I plotted obviously doesn't show the same local maxima in the underlying function, and I would like to figure out how to plot the image using `A[:,:,0]` to get the same type of colormap image you generated, while still utilizing the `A[:,:,0]` method so that I can just change values of `A[:,:,1]`, and `A[:,:,2]` to get the desired result.

Comment: I found the issue, matplotlib expects values between 0 and 1 for RGB images, so you have to normalize the values. See my edit.